# Clearing of datagrid view in vb.net 2010

Tags: datagridview, vb.net-2010

my question is how to clear a datagrid view in vb.net 2010
i have tried DatGridView1.Clear() but it only works once
and i would like to clear my datagrid every time i click the load button
hers my code

```
Private Sub Button15_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button15.Click
        OpenFileDialog1.Title = "Please Select a File"
        OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:temp"
        OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    End Sub
Private Sub OpenFileDialog1_FileOk(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles OpenFileDialog1.FileOk
        dgQuotation.DataSource = Nothing
        Dim strm As System.IO.Stream
        strm = OpenFileDialog1.OpenFile()
        strPath = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        If Not (strm Is Nothing) Then
            dgQuotation.DataSource = Nothing
            ' Dim col As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
            'column declaration
            dgQuotation.ColumnCount = 43
            columnDeclaration()
            For Each line As String In System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(strPath)
                dgQuotation.Rows.Add(line.Split("!"))
            Next
            strm.Close()
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same problem. Setting `DatGridView1.DataSource = "null"` works